# optical flow: how to fill in the area behind a moving object?

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, opticalflow, inpainting

I need to apply a style to a video using the optical flow algorithm. However, there's a problem: how to fill in the area behind a moving object.

please suggest me an algorithm that can take the adjacent image area and stretch it into the area behind the object as it moves.

Comment: Show example images (frames) of such movement (input) and also show images of problematic output with the area that needs filling. Four frames from each input and output is enough. Sounds like you simply need a linear interpolation... I can only explain based on your images